# create dynamic selector in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jquery plugin and my html is like

```
<select class="filter">
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
    <option value="value3">value3</option>
</select>
```

my plugin code is like

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.filterCategory = function( options ) {
        $(".filter option").each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(this).attr("data-val",text);
        });
        // other code...
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

and i call it like

```
$("select.filter").filterCategory();
```

the problem is if i want to call this plugin by id like

```
$("select#filter").filterCategory();
```

or by other class or id like

```
 $("select.new_filter").filterCategory();
 $("select#new_filter").filterCategory();
```

then the html will be like

```
<select id="filter">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

then i will have to make changes on my plugin. It means it works only for ***.filter*** only. How can i make this code dynamic

```
$(".filter option").each(function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword to reference the elements that the plugin was intialised on:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.filterCategory = function(options) {
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).attr('data-val', text);
    });

    // other code...
  };
}(jQuery));
```

You should also ensure you return a jQuery object from your plugin, assuming you wish to maintain the chaining pattern that jQuery uses. Finally note that you can simplify the `each()` loop to just call `attr()` only:

```
$(this).find('option').attr('data-val', function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

This is of course assuming that you *need* to have the `data-val` attribute within the DOM. If not, I'd suggest using `data()` instead to use jQuery's internal cache.

Comment: $(this).attr('data-val', text);    this is how i was creating a data-val in dropdown option and inserting its text in it.